# Does $1/(1+z^2)$ have an antiderivative?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Does $1/(1+z^2)$ defined on $1<|z|<\infty$ have an antiderivative? My approach:

Partial fraction decomposition:
$$\frac 1 {1+z^2}=\frac{i/2}{z+i}-\frac{i/2}{z-i}$$

Let $\gamma$ be the path $\gamma(t)=2e^{2\pi i t}$. Then we see:

$$\int_\gamma\frac 1 {1+z^2}dz=\frac i 2\left(\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z+i}dz-\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z-i}dz\right)$$

I want this to be not null because then I would get that the function does not have an antiderivative since then the integral over closed paths like gamma would equal null. However, I think this is not the case, it seems this evaluates to null.

But I don't see how to calculate $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z+i}dz$ and $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z-i}dz$. I cannot apply Cauchy's integral formula because $|i|=1$, so $i$ is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: Your path $\gamma(t)$ goes around a circle of radius $2$ about the origin. Are you sure that $i$ is not in the domain for $z$ restricted to the path?

Comment: But that shouldn't matter, does it? As the theorem is stated on e.g. wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula, it requires that the closed disk is fully contained in $U$. That is not the case here, because $i$ is contained in the closed disk of radius $2$. However, I have another idea: $1/(z-i)$ has only one pole at $i$. So it's domain is star shaped, take $0$ as the star point. Furthermore, it's holomorphic, therefore the integral equals $0$. Is this right?

Comment: Extending a holomorphic function on one domain to a meromorphic function on a larger domain does not change the value of any integrals around loops in the original domain.

Comment: Just use the [complex logarithm form](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/02/) of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and you have the antiderivative.